# JavaScript array.length returning correct number, but console.log(array) empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm getting form data for HTML check boxes here:

```
host1 = document.getElementById("host1").checked;
host2 = document.getElementById("host2").checked;
host3 = document.getElementById("host3").checked;
host4 = document.getElementById("host4").checked;
host1Value = document.getElementById("host1").value;
host2Value = document.getElementById("host2").value;
host3Value = document.getElementById("host3").value;
host4Value = document.getElementById("host4").value;
```

Appending to an empty array those which are checked and setting a variable to the array length:

```
if (host1) {hostsArray.push(host1Value); };
if (host2) {hostsArray.push(host2Value); };
if (host3) {hostsArray.push(host3Value); };
if (host4) {hostsArray.push(host4Value); };
hostsNum = hostsArray.length;
```

When I log hostNum and hostsArray to the console, hostNum correctly identifies the number of checked boxes so the array is reporting the correct length, but the array logs as empty. I'm at a loss.

Comment: How are you initializing `hostArray`? Make sure it's `[]` and not `{}`.

Comment: How are you logging the array to the console? Have you tried `console.dir(hostsArray)`?

Comment: I initialized with hostsArray = new Array();

console.dir(hostsArray) shows Array[2] but no values.

Comment: Use a loop from 1 to 4, please.

Comment: @Bergi It was originally, but I changed it to debug this issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: possibly related to [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: @Bergi You're right! Firebug does it all fine. What an odd bug. Should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine in Chrome, you can also see it on this JSbin : http://jsbin.com/eSuwAri/2

I have refactor it with a simple for loop, but it's almost the same as your example. I presume the problem is elsewhere in your js or html code.

HTML :

```
<input id="host1" type="checkbox" name="host1name" value="host1value">host1 text<br>
<input id="host2" type="checkbox" name="host2name" value="host2value">host2 text<br>
<input id="host3" type="checkbox" name="host3name" value="host3value">host3 text<br> 
<input id="host4" type="checkbox" name="host4name" value="host4value">host4 text<br>               
<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
```

Javascript :

```
    function test(){
        var hostsArray = new Array();
        for (var i=1;i<=4;i++){ 
            var id = "host" + i;
            var checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
            var value = document.getElementById(id).value;

            if (checked) {
                hostsArray.push(value) 
            };
        }
        hostsNum = hostsArray.length;

        console.log("Array : ")
        console.log(hostsArray);
        console.log("number of value : " +  hostsNum);
    }
```

Console output:

```
"Array : "
["host1value", "host2value", "host3value", "host4value"]
"number of value : 4"
```

Comment: It turned out that the code was fine, but Chrome's log had a bug. Everything behaved as anticipated in Firebug.